# If a Barbarian/Sorcerer multiclass casts False Life on himself, then rages, will the spell's effect remain active?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, barbarian, rage

In an adventure I am playing, I play a barbarian 1 / sorcerer 1, and I am in a dispute with my DM. My DM says that if I cast *False Life* on myself, then Rage, the spell's effect will not remain.

Page 48 of the *Player's Handbook* says, under the description of the [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/barbarian#Rage) feature:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can't cast them or concentrate on
>   them while raging.

Because of this rule, am I able to keep the effects I cast on myself?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Yes, because *False Life* does not require concentration.

The [*false life*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/false-life) spell has a duration of 1 hour, and doesn't require concentration.

Because it requires no concentration, if you cast it before raging and your rage occurs within its one-hour duration, the spell will still be in effect.